# Graphics window and user input

Tags: python, drawing, screen, resolution, turtle-graphics

My code is specific to screen resolution so I need to get the script to act based on the user's resolution.

I have tried:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

as well as pip install pypiwin32 to get this ^ code to work, but it didn't.

My current iteration of code looks like this:

```
resolution = input ("What resolution is your monitor?")
print (resolution)

if resolution == "1440":
```

However this interferes with the full screen command:

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
SW_MAXIMISE = 3
hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMISE)
```

After the user types "1440", the window starts minimized, how can I get the window to start maximized after input. The window works fine without the input prompt, BTW, that's how I know that's the problem.

Comment: turtle has dialog windows to ask for values and you don't need `input()` - [textinput()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput), [numinput()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.numinput)

Comment: I don't know why I though you use `turtle` so I ask: what do you use for graphics window: `turtle`, `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PySide`, `PyGtk`, `PyGame`, `Graphics.py`, `wxPython`, etc.

Comment: I do use turtles. It's in the title of the question :)

Comment: Maybe it was in title but now there is no turtle in title.

Comment: turtle is built on top of `tkinter` and you may access tkinter's root window with `turtle.getscreen()._root`. It has function to get screen size: `print( turtle.getscreen()._root.winfo_screenwidth() )`

Comment: Can you use turtle's own `window_height()` and `window_width()` methods of the turtle screen?  Or are you looking for something else (e.g. DPI)?  The turtle methods don't account for space lost to *chrome* like borders and title bar -- they are literally the window, not necessarily the turtle screen area.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I fixed it with the turtles window input. Resolution  = str.lower(window.textinput("Resolution", "What resolution should this run at?"))